# Why Ransack doesn't show any search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I refer to the official teaching and also read all the similar Q&A on Stackoverflow, but I am not using Pagy and AJAX, so it is not the same error.

I'm trying to search for the value of the `name` column on `Task` model. But when I enter a keyword that matches an existing name value and press `Search`, the result is blank. I can't figure out why?

This is part of the controller:

```
  def index
    @name = Task.ransack(name_cont: params[:q])
    @tasks = @name.result
    puts @tasks
  end
```

This is View

```
<%= search_form_for @name do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Search for" %>
  <%= f.search_field :name, placeholder: "Mission Name" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<h1><%= t('task_list') %></h1>
  <ul>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <li>
        <%= task.name %>
        <%= t('task_status') %>：<%= task.status %>
          <%= link_to t('task_cont') , task_path(task) %>
            <%= link_to t('task_do_edit') , edit_task_path(task) %>
            <%= link_to t('task_do_kill') , task_path(task), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: t('task_do_sure') } %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

This is the terminal log

```
Started GET "/my_task_list?q%5Bname%5D=TT&commit=%E6%90%9C%E5%B0%8B" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-03-18 15:22:49 +0800
Processing by TasksController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"q"=>{"name"=>"TT"}, "commit"=>"搜尋"}
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."name" ILIKE '%{"name"=>"TT"}%'
  ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:14:in `puts'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering tasks/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered tasks/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 298)
  Rendered tasks/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 830)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 83.5ms | Allocations: 3871)
Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 84.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 5108)
```

Comment: It's `Task.ransack(name_cont: params[:q][:name])`

Comment: @razvans Thank you so much, I misunderstood what ```[:q]``` does

Comment: The idea is to send something like `q: { name_cont: 'TT' }` and do `Task.ransack(params[:q])`

Comment: @razvans If I didn't write ```[:name]```, what would be inside ```[:q]```?

Comment: { name_cont: 'TT'}

Comment: @razvans You mean, the content of both ways is the same? I'm a little confused. Also, when I use the second way of writing, the ````undefined method []``` error occurs soon, so I rewrite it as ```params[:q] && params[:q][:name]```. However, this seems to render sort_link invalid.

Comment: Keep it as it if it's working.

Comment: I will add an answer tonight.

Comment: I try ```Task.ransack(name_cont: params.dig(:q,:name))```, but ```sort_link``` still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should say `Task.ransack(name_cont: params[:q][:name])` because your params look like this: `{"q"=>{"name"=>"TT"} }`.

But, you are using the same action, `index` to render the intial page (when the user lands on it) and also after `Search` is pressed. When the page renders first, i.e `http://localhost/tasks`, `q` parameter does not exist and writing `params[:q][:name]` will obviously fail because `params[:q]` is `nil`.

Ideally, you should keep `index` to render the search form and have another action for `search`.

But, if you want to keep everything as is you could write it as follows:

Assuming you have a `TasksController`:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @query = Task.ransack(params[:q])
    @tasks = @query.result
  end
end
```

And the search form is on `/tasks`:

```
<%= search_form_for @query do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Search for" %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_cont, placeholder: "Mission Name" %>
  <%= f.select :status_eq, Task.statuses.map { |key, value| [key.titleize, value] }, prompt: 'Choose Status' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
....
```

You see I added `name_cont` as the search field. You could add more, i.e `status_eq`, and all will be sent to the server in `params[:q]` when you press `Search`.

Pay attention to the logs to see how `q` looks like and what query is performed in `Tasks`.

`Task Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."name" ILIKE '%test%'`

Comment: Before this, I used to use search_key in order to make sort_link work: ```@name = Task.ransack(params[:name], search_key: :name)```, but this made the search invalid. I've read the complete read me, but I still don't understand most of it.

Comment: Sorry, I have two new questions. First, since I added fields in the View table (showing information such as ```created_at```), the ```sort_link``` for name has not worked. Second, if I want to sort by more fields (such as ```created_at```), what should I do? (Adding the search_field symbol directly will cause a parameter error)

Comment: I can not add more, i.e status_eq, it will be ```wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)```

Comment: I'll update the answer tonight.

Comment: Updated with the search by status

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand some of the issues here. First, what does ```titleize``` mean? Second, I have set the sort_link for the name and status columns: ```<th><%= sort_link(@query, t('task_name')) %></th>``` and `` `<th><%= sort_link(@query, t('task_status')) %></th>```, but no matter how you click it has no effect.